# Camera2 CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE - INACTIVE

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am using `camera2` api, based on Google example.
Work fine on my device, but doesn't work on emulator(and maybe some other devices).

The reason `CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE` is in state `CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_INACTIVE`.

Part of the code(identical to Google example)

```
case STATE_WAITING_LOCK: {

                Integer afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);

                if (afState == null) {
                    captureStillPicture();
                } else if (CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState ||
                        CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState) {
                    // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                    Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                    if (aeState == null ||
                            aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                        mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                        captureStillPicture();
                    } else {
                        runPrecaptureSequence();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
```

As we can see if the state is `INACTIVE` nothing happen.
I am afraid that this can happen not only on emulator, so my question is not safe to take picture even if `AUTO FOCUS STATE INACTIVE`? and what to do about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In emulator, auto focus mode might not be available.

So in addition to the null check, try changing the condition to the inactive state as well.

```
     if (afState == null || CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_INACTIVE == afState) {
                         captureStillPicture();
     }
```